# Swift closure with multiple params

Tags: swift

I am trying to define a Swift closure with two arguments but it is throwing compilation errors. What am I doing wrong?

```
 var processor: (CMSampleBuffer, CVPixelBuffer) throws -> Void { (sampleBuffer, outputPixelBuffer) in
    ....
}
```

EDIT: An `=` was missing which was correctly pointed out in the comments. But now I am trying to pass this closure as a param and it is giving compilation errors in declaration:

```
 func process(_ processor: ((_ sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer,  toPixelBuffer:CVPixelBuffer) throws)? = nil) {


 }
```

Comment: Would be easier to help you if you would post the compilation errors you are getting

Comment: You're missing an `=` between `Void` and `{` in the first line.

Comment: You are right, = was missing. Syntax is little complex. But now I have trouble passing this closure as argument to function. What is the right syntax to declare it as param?

Comment: Ongoing questions are not something that comply with SO standards. Your initial question got addressed, please open another one if you have new questions afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

So the following code seems to pass in a Playground:

```
func process(_ processor: ((String, String))? = nil) {

}
```

I am pretty sure the main problem is that you want to force `throws` as a keyword. I don't think that's possible in any way, I would rather propose to use a `Result` `enum` pattern that looks more or less like this:

```
enum ProcessResult {
    case success(someReturnValue: YourType) // Or no associated value if you just want to know it worked
    case failed(anError: Error)
}
```

By requiring the block to return a `ProcessResult` you can enforce something you might use a try/catch for in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

[Function Type](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html#ID449) needs to be written in this syntax:

`(` *ArgumentList* `)` *`throws`* `->` *ResultType*

(Simplified, you can find a full description in the link above.)

The keyword `throws` is optional according to your requirement, but `->` *ResultType* is required even if the *ResultType* is `Void`.

And *ArgumentList* cannot have parameter labels, you need to use `_` as parameter label when you want to show parameter names for readability.

So, your `process(_:)` should be something like this:

```
func process(_ processor: ((_ sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer,  _ toPixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) throws -> Void)? = nil) {
    //...
}
```

Or else, if you define a typealias for the parameter type, you can rewrite it as follows:

```
typealias ProcessorType = (_ sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer,  _ toPixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) throws -> Void

func process(_ processor: ProcessorType? = nil) {
    //...
}
```

---

One more, when you ask something about *compilation errors*, it is strongly recommended to show whole error message.

You can find a copyable text through the Report Navigator in the Navigator pane (in the Left side of Xcode).